# d3 how to scale between number to color when lengths are different

Tags: d3.js

How can I use `d3.scaleOrdinal` when the domain and range are not the same length?

I have this array of colors:

```
 const color = [ 'red', 'green', 'blue' ];
```

When I want to scale numbers to it its easy when I have 3 numbers

```
scaleOrdinal().domain([1,2,3]).range(color)
```

but what can I do if I have 10 numbers?
I want that numbers 1,2,3 will get red, 4,5,6 will get green and 7,8,9 will get blue.

How can I do that?
Im using `d3` v4

Answer (score 0):

Write your own scale:

```js
const color = [ 'red', 'green', 'blue' ];

var colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(d3.range(1,11)).range(color);

function ordinalGroup(ordinalBase) {
  return function(v) {
    var domain = ordinalBase.domain();
    var range = ordinalBase.range();
    var idx = domain.indexOf(v);
    if (idx === -1) return range[0];
    return range[Math.floor(idx/(domain.length/range.length))];
  };
}

var colorGroup = ordinalGroup(colorScale);

console.log(colorScale.domain().map(d => [d, colorGroup(d)] ));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```